# How to return many conditional strings when creating shortcode in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to shortcode and PHP. I'm creating a shortcode by following many [tutorials such as this](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-custom-shortcodes-for-wordpress-in-two-minutes/). Is the below safe and recommended to do when trying to add a long output conditional string in a shortcode? Or is there a better way?

```
function some_shortcode() {
 if(/*condition*/) {
  $return = "Something...";
 }
 $return .= "...interesting";
 
 return $return;
}
```

Comment: please tell us more about your conditions

Comment: @Codeschreiber.de It's something like `if ( wp_is_application_passwords_available_for_user( $user_id ) || ! wp_is_application_passwords_supported() ) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 1

check for userid, in case not loggin in return "not logged in"
after check your own condition and combine to a string

```
add_shortcode('yourShortcodeName', 'yourShortcodeFunction');

function yourShortcodeFunction(){
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    
    if(!$user_id || $user_id == 0){
        return "not logged in";
    }
    $return = "";

    if ( wp_is_application_passwords_available_for_user( $user_id ) || ! wp_is_application_passwords_supported() ) {
        $return.= "Whatever";
    }

    $return.= " another value";

    return $return;
}
```

#### Solution 2

check for userid, in case not loggin in return "not logged in"
after check your own condition and combine to a array and implode to output string

```
add_shortcode('yourShortcodeName', 'yourShortcodeFunction');

function yourShortcodeFunction(){
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if(!$user_id || $user_id == 0){
        return "not logged in";
    }
    $return = [];

    if ( wp_is_application_passwords_available_for_user( $user_id ) || ! wp_is_application_passwords_supported() ) {
        $return[] = "Whatever";
    }

    $return[] = " another value";

    return implode(' ' , $return);
}
```